# Avoiding any automatic variables when `std::vector` resizes its memory

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I have an `std::vector<SomeType>`, whereas `SomeType` is a `struct` instantiated from various template parameters.

Eventually in my specific case it turns out to be a large structure (about 1MB). Allocating such a structure on the stack (i.e. using an automatic variable of this type) immediately leads to the stack overflow. But since `std::vector` allocates the memory on the heap - there *should* be no problem.

Surprisingly there **is** a problem with this. Specifically, the problem is with the initialization. I do the following:

```
std::vector<SomeType> myVec;
// ...
myVec.resize(N);
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    SomeType& x = myVec[i];
    // initialize it
}
```

I get a stack overflow exception in `myVec.resize()`. Stepping inside `resize()` with the debugger revealed that if `resize()` causes the `vector` to grow - besides of allocating the memory it also initializes the new elements by "default values".

The "default value" is obtained by creating an **automatic** variable of the given type, using default (i.e. empty) constructor, and assigning the new element to it.

I wonder if there's a way to overcome this. I mean, tell `std::vector` not to initialize the new elements. But I'd like to achieve this **without generating unneeded code**.

I can think of using a `vector` of (smart/shared/scoped/unique) pointers to type. Or alternatively use `push_back` whereas each new element is allocated on heap. But all this inevitable involves extra code. Which is not justified.

Is there a way to achieve what I need? Whereas:

- still using `std::vector<SomeType>`
- No redundant heap allocations

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `SomeType`is about 1MB in size? Maybe you should allocate its members on heap too?

Comment: I am guessing your struct has at least one huge array in it, right? How about making that array dynamic (for example with a vector)?

Comment: Refactor SomeType to be something simpler.

Comment: @yuri kilochek: No, because the whole vector is allocated on heap. No real need in 2 allocations, and redunant inderections during access

Comment: @Shahbaz: This means extra heap allocations. I don't want this.

Comment: @Tadeusz A. Kadłubowski: Every single bit of `MyType` contains useful information.

Comment: *But all this inevitable involves extra code. Which is not justified.* The fact that without modification your application crashes is a good justification for changing the code, at least in my books... Voting to close as not a question until you decide what you want: if you don't want changes, then there is no answer...

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: Naturally the code should be changed. But there are *so* many options to fix this without using `std::vector` that are superior w.r.t. the resulting code. My question was solely regarding `std::vector`. Is this possible or not.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by saving one memory allocation? Making some arrays dynamic has added benefits that could compensate for the extra allocation. For example, if you need to sort, swapping becomes pointer swap instead of array swap. In C++11 stuff, moving also becomes simple pointer assignments.

Comment: @Shahbaz: I just don't want to do what is not necessary. Anyway, my specific question was is it possible to achieve what I need **without** doing extra things. I knew how to solve this in other ways before asking the question.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Sure there's an answer.  Increase the stack size.  (`ulimit -s` under Unix.  Don't know under Windows---I think you have to do it when building the process.)  If that's his only problem, then increasing the stack size is the simplest solution.

Comment: @James Kanze: No offenses, but you all miss my point. I **know** how to solve this. Actually the easiest solution is just not using `std::vector`. Other alternatives, such as `scoped_array` are perfectly good in my case. My question was very specific: is it possible to solve this using vector with exact parameters and without extra things, for which one pays at run-time.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I agree, this can be solved at the OS level (1M is not that much for stack size, which made me think that it might be an embedded system), but as you might have noticed from valdo's response to your comment he is not really looking for *answers* (*I **know** how to solve this*). He just wants someone to tell him what he wants to hear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++03 it's impossible:

- Vectors cannot contain uninitialized elements
- Vectors *only* know how to initialize elements by copying

Therefore you need an element to copy from. It doesn't fit on the stack (ruling out the default argument) and you don't want to explicitly put it elsewhere, so you're out of luck.

In C++11 there are new means of initializing elements in a container, and for example the `size_t` constructor no longer takes an extra default argument. Instead it value-initializes each element, which is probably what you want.

So in C++11, the answer is `std::vector<SomeType> myVec(N);`. Perhaps you could check whether your compiler has a C++11 mode that you could use to compile your code. Of course, migrating to C++11 isn't completely trivial.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is the only one that answers my question.

Comment: "It doesn't fit on the stack, and you don't want to put it on the heap"---so that leaves static memory.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I ignored that accidentally, but it turns out that the questioner doesn't want it there either (see comments elsewhere) - the goal is to do it without an element to copy from. Since I said, "the heap" rather than "dynamically allocated memory", I might be able to weasel out with the observation that on desktop-like systems, static memory is in point of fact allocated from the same source anyway, by the dynamic linker ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use reserve and then push_back.

Comment: From the question, "Or alternatively use push_back whereas each new element is allocated on heap. But all this inevitable involves extra code. Which is not justified."

Comment: Use C++11, reserve and then emplace_back?

Comment: My point is that the questioner has already considered your suggestion in the question, and rejected it. Albeit for reasons only vaguely defined.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to change `SomeType` so that it is smaller. But resizing vector without using stack nor heap is possible. Just use a static local variable:

```
static SomeType intialValue;
myVec.resize(N, initialValue);
```

Be aware, that such function is not re-entrant.

Comment: Yes, It's not re-entrant. Plus it's not thread-safe. And, in any case, this means extra code generated.

Comment: @valdo What extra code? I writing one line too much for you? If you want some different behavior you have to change **something**

Comment: No. I meant the machine code in the executable. Using `static` leads to (huge) increase in the global memory consumed by the executable. Plus some extra in function prolog, ensuring the `initialValue` is initialized. Plus extra CRT cleanup code at program termination that ensure the static object is destroyed (if it was created). And the point is that all this is absolutely not necessary. It's just a consequence of an imperfect design.

Comment: Doesn't help with the questioner's objections, but you could make it re-entrant by using a (static and/or const) global variable instead of a local.

Comment: What's not thread safe (or not reentrant) about it?  C++11 requires it to be thread safe (as long as you never modify `initialValue`), and pre-C++11 compilers (at least some of them) made it thread safe anyway.

Comment: @JamesKanze Probably you are right. I just thought this huge `SomeType` may not feel well being copied in parallel. I don't know its internals.

Comment: "at least some of them" = "not all of them", i.e. the code is not in general thread-safe, although it may be on some implementations. https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/08/85901.aspx?Redirected=true. I'm dubious of the claim that non-thread safety is required by the standard -- obviously the C++03 standard doesn't say what happens in any multi-threaded program, I don't see how it could require that the example code fails. But I trust Chen to report whether MSVC did thread-safe static initialization or not. It didn't.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure it's not re-entrant. For example you cannot safely call it from a the handler of a signal that has interrupted the initialization of `initialValue`, nor can the constructor of `SomeType` call it recursively. That last case isn't solved by making it global, though.

Comment: @SteveJessop You can't call much of anything from a handler of a signal.  I'm not really sure what the standard says about calling the function from the constructor of the static value itself---I suspect that it's undefined behavior.  But C++11 clearly says that you can call the function from two different threads, and it should work.  (Of course, if the static object isn't const, and you attempt to modify it later, you'll need protection.)

Comment: Fair enough. There's a better way in C++11 anyway, though. C++03 implementations in which this is thread-safe and that have 1MB of memory to waste still covers a lot of ground.